# Find the sum of the numbers in the sequence

Tags: c++, string, sum, char, numbers

Input a string and print the sum of the numbers in the string

Input: abc123kjewd456

Output: 579

I want code it with pointer in string, array, loop, and lots of way, Can you help me use the best way?                     .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help], take the SO [tour], and read [ask]. Also please read about [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Also please learn how to create a [mre] of ***your own*** attempt, and [edit] your question to show it together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Or just vote to close since, to me, they’re just hoping someone will do their homework for them.

Comment: To get the **best** way, write the minimal code that produces correct code.  Then post to [codereview.se] and ask for improvements.

Comment: Please clarify "lots of way".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews "minimal code" isn't really something Code Review wants. MVCEs are desirable on Stack Overflow, but 'VCEs' are more CR's thing.

Answer (score -1):

```
int sumInString(const char *str) {
  // valid str
  if (str == NULL || *str == '\0') {
    return 0;
  }
  int num = 0;
  int res = 0;
  int i = 0;
  while (str[i] != '\0') {
    if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9') /*is numerical*/ {
      num *= 10;
      num += str[i] - '0'; // char->int conversion
    } else {
      res += num;
      num = 0;
    }
    ++i;
  }
  res += num; // add the remainder
  return res;
}
```